# How to use axios.put to send JSON to ASP.NET controller

Tags: asp.net, json, reactjs, put

I'm trying to send a PUT request with JSON data using the following client code:

```
const url = new URL(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/datas/edit/${id}`);
axios.put(url, data);
```

And on the server side, when I'm trying to look at in the `HttpRequest.Form`, the Controller throws `InvalidOperationException` exception . The message is `Incorrect Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8`.

```
[HttpPut("edit/{id}")]
public void Edit([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Data data)
...
```

I also tried `axios.put(url, JSON.stringify(data));` but server returns 415.

EDIT: I tried with Postman instead of my front-end:

[image]

```
public class A { public int /*or string*/ A1 { get; set; } }
[HttpPut("edit/{id}")]
public void EditQuestion([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] A a) ...
```

IMPORTANT:

I shouldn't have looked at HttpRequest.Form because I'm sending JSON data and it should be parsed into my model.

Comment: If you catch the error on the server do you get more info about what is wrong with it. Can you compare the model on the server with what is sent by the browser (look in the browser devtools network tab, you can even copy the request as javascript). If you can't figure it out can you post both the copied request from devtools network and the model?

Comment: That is not useful, in Chrome devtools you can right click the request and choose copy => as fetch or curl. That request can be compared with the model on the server.

Comment: A1 is not an int when you send it

Comment: @HMR, I tried `{ "A1": 1 }`, tried change to string in the model. The error is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the json response from postman returns a string, instead your "A" class has an int property for A1.

Try changing the class to:

```
public class A { public string A1 { get; set; } }
```

Comment: What if you specify content-type to "application/json" in your client side request ?

Comment: There is also a mention to utf-8. Try to specify the content-type in the request without the encoding.